# Populating default value from another table

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

At a bit of a loss here. Basically I have a Product page in the admin section and at the bottom of that I have an TabularInline that let's me choose sizes for the product and set a price. This works but I'm trying to get it so that it pulls the default price from the Sizes table to be the initial value.

I tried the following:

```
class Size(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    default_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'sizes'
        ordering = ['-created_at']
        verbose_name_plural = 'Sizes'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    def default_price(self):
        return self.default_price
```

And then

```
class ProductOption(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    size = models.ForeignKey(Size)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2, default=Size.default_price)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

It validates, but when I load the admin page I get the following:

unbound method get_default_price() must be called with Size instance as first argument (got nothing instead)

Not sure where else to go from here. I've been looking over the Django docs forever trying to find something else to try. Any ideas?

Comment: You'll probably want to change your ``updated_at`` fields to be ``auto_now``, not ``auto_now_add`, else they will be the same as the ``created_at`` fields.

Answer (score 0):

So, you can override the save method, and if there is no self.id, you can populate some other fields first, that's what sticks out at me as the best solution.

just as an example:

```
def save(*args, **kwargs):
    if not self.id:
        self.size = SomeOtherModel.objects.get(pk=size)

    super(Size, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: I think that may be a step after what I'm trying to populate. In the admin section there is a form, with a drop down and a price text box. I'd like to pre-populate the text box with the default price when selecting the name from the drop-down. The furthest I've been able to get is populating it with the row ID. The actual data I want resides in a different table than the model for that form is attached. I can't seem to find a way to intelligently link the default_price that resides in the separate table to the form populated by the options table.

Answer (score 0):

You have several issues here:

`Size.default_price` is a callable object, so python is trying to call it when setting the default value of your ProductOption. What you might be looking for is:

```
class Size(models.Model):
    # Other stuff here
    @property
    def default_price(self):
        return self.default_price
```

However, this then causes another, deeper error. If you had the following:

```
size = Size()
size.default_price
```

You would wind up with a StackOverflow, due to infinite recursion. This property calls itself. A solution is to have the property name different to the attribute, or in this simplest case, it already acts a bit like a property. You can just remove the whole `default_price` definition.

However, you are calling `Size.default_price`, which is not bound to anything if you call it on `Size`, a class, not on an instance of that class.

What you want to actually do is kind of what Issac Kelly suggests, but more so.

```
class ProductOption(models.Model):
    # column definitions

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProductOption, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.size and not self.price:
            self.price = self.size.default_price
```

This means that when you instantiate a ProductOption, it will automatically set the price based on the size, if there isn't already a price.

You might also want to do this check at save time, as otherwise:

```
po = ProductOption()
po.size = Size.objects.get(pk=1)
po.save()
# po.price is not set now!

po = ProductOption.objects.get(pk=po.pk)
# po.price is set now!
```

So, you could have the following:

```
class ProductOption(models.Model):
    # columns

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProductOption, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.set_default_price()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.set_default_price()
        super(ProductOption, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def set_default_price(self):
        if self.size and not self.price:
            self.price = self.size.default_price
```

Note the difference in order of the super() call: when initialising the object, we want to call the parent's `__init__` first, but when saving, we want to (possibly) set the default value first, then call the parent class's `save` method.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. I definitely understand the logic behind it now. Running into a rather obscure error. 'Exception Type: DoesNotExist'. If I run through the code it's stemming from:


`if self.size and not self.price:
    self.price = self.size.default_price`

If I replace it with just self.price = '20.00' it loads the page with no exceptions, however it doesn't set the price in the admin form. 

Is it somehow effected by the admin code? I added this comment plus code to Pastebin. Can't put it in a comment I guess.

[Pastebin of this comment](http://pastebin.com/K6PVX0ST)

Comment: I've had issues where it is hard to know what order the admin does thing in.

Comment: I'd make sure it works from the console first, then try to add admin support.